# trying to recreate carl bot echo command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so i was trying to recreate the echo command but like, in carl bot when you use the command it doesnt show the users slash command but only show the bot message and i dont know how to recreate that part

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName('echo')
.setDescription('Replies with your input!')
.addStringOption(option =>
    option.setName('input')
        .setDescription('The input to echo back')
        .setRequired(false)),
        async execute(interaction) {
            const input = interaction.options.getString("input")
            await interaction.reply(input)
        },
}
```

Comment: _"it doesnt show the users slash command but only show the bot message"_ It's probably a good idea to post the differences by adding images to your question.

Comment: You're using `interaction.reply()` to reply to the uses command. You likely want `interaction.channel.send()`